Animate with scale and opacity in SwiftUI
How can I animate the circle image with scale from 0 to 1 while animating with starting position at 7 o'clock & scaling end position at 11 o'clock along the circumference of the circle and then animate with opacity from 1 to 0 while 11 o'clock to 3 o'clock. Then reposition the image back to 7 o'clock & replay the animation in a loop. With the following code, I'm able to scale and rotate at the same time but it does not follow along the circumference. I not sure how to offset the animation during the scale & rotate such that it stays along the circle.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var startAngle: Double = -45
    @State private var endAngle: Double = 120
    @State private var animationValue: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let width: CGFloat = 60
            Circle()
                .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1.0)
                .frame(width: width)
                .overlay {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        .offset(x: -width/2)
                        .modifier(ScaleAndRotateModifier(value: animationValue,
                                                         startAngle: startAngle,
                                                         endAngle: endAngle))
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                                animationValue = 1.0
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.black)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ScaleAndRotateModifier: AnimatableModifier {
    var value: Double
    var startAngle: Double
    var endAngle: Double
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: startAngle + value * endAngle), anchor: .center)
            .scaleEffect(value * 0.5)
    }
}


I wasn't quite sure how to describe the positions so picture the position of the hour hand of a clock. The image starts at the 7 o'clock position with scale 0. It then animates along the circumference of the Circle to the 11 o'clock position while also scaling to 1(full size) over a duration of 1 second. It should then animate from 11 o'clock to 3 o'clock while only it's opacity reduces to 0 over a duration of 1 second. On completion, the circle goes back to 7 o'clock and the animation repeats. I hope this clears things up a bit.

@Sweeper, it should just move to 7 o'clock with opacity reset to 1 and scale reset to 0. Animation duration of 1 second. Animation restarts from here and proceeds as before.

Okay, I have edited my answer to do that. I personally think the circle going back instantaneously is prettier though :)

Since this animation involves multiple stages, it would be convenient to use a keyframeAnimator here.
Write a struct with all the properties you want to animate:
struct AnimatedProperties {
    var angle: Angle = .degrees(120)
    var scale: CGFloat = 0
    var opacity: CGFloat = 1
}

Then you can do
let width: CGFloat = 60
Circle()
    .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1.0)
    .frame(width: width)
    .overlay {
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .keyframeAnimator(initialValue: AnimatedProperties()) { content, properties in
                content
                    .scaleEffect(properties.scale)
                    .opacity(properties.opacity)
                    .offset(x: width / 2 * cos(properties.angle.radians), y: width / 2 * sin(properties.angle.radians))
            } keyframes: { properties in
                KeyframeTrack(\.angle) {
                    // angle goes from 120 to 480 over the course of 3 seconds
                    LinearKeyframe(.degrees(480), duration: 3)
                }
                KeyframeTrack(\.scale) {
                    // scale goes to 1 during the first second
                    LinearKeyframe(1, duration: 1)
                    // then stays there for 1 second
                    LinearKeyframe(1, duration: 1)
                    // then goes back to 0 in the last second
                    LinearKeyframe(0, duration: 1)
                }
                KeyframeTrack(\.opacity) {
                    // opacity stays at 1 for the first second
                    LinearKeyframe(1, duration: 1)
                    // then goes to 0 in the next second
                    LinearKeyframe(0, duration: 1)
                    // then goes back to 1 again
                    LinearKeyframe(1, duration: 1)
                }
            }

    }

Notice the line:
.offset(x: width / 2 * cos(properties.angle.radians), y: width / 2 * sin(properties.angle.radians))

This is how you compute the required offset for a given angle.
In my opinion, this animation looks a bit funny. At around 2 seconds, the circle "flashes", because its opacity goes from non-zero to zero, then back to non-zero again, very quickly. To me this doesn't feel coherent. I think this set of key frames look much better, where the animation is only two seconds long, and the circle instantaneously moves from 3 o'clock to 7 o'clock to start a new cycle.
} keyframes: { properties in
    KeyframeTrack(\.angle) {
        // angle goes from 120 to 360 over the course of 2 seconds
        LinearKeyframe(.degrees(360), duration: 2)
    }
    KeyframeTrack(\.scale) {
        // scale goes to 1 during the first second
        LinearKeyframe(1, duration: 1)
        // then stays there for another second
        LinearKeyframe(1, duration: 1)
    }
    KeyframeTrack(\.opacity) {
        // opacity stays at 1 for the first second
        LinearKeyframe(1, duration: 1)
        // then goes to 0 in the next second
        LinearKeyframe(0, duration: 1)
    }
}


If keyframeAnimator is not available for your target iOS version, you can still use your view modifier approach, but you'd need to calculate the scale and opacity manually.
struct ContentView: View {
    let startAngle: Angle = .degrees(120)
    let endAngle: Angle = .degrees(480)
    @State private var animationValue: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let width: CGFloat = 60
            Circle()
                .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 1.0)
                .frame(width: width)
                .overlay {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                        .modifier(ScaleAndRotateModifier(value: animationValue,
                                                         startAngle: startAngle.radians,
                                                         endAngle: endAngle.radians,
                                                         radius: width / 2))
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                                animationValue = 1.0
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.black)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ScaleAndRotateModifier: ViewModifier, Animatable, _RemoveGlobalActorIsolation {
    var value: Double
    let startAngle: Double
    let endAngle: Double
    let radius: Double
    
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }
    
    var scale: CGFloat {
        if value * 3 < 1 {
            value * 3
        } else if value * 3 < 2 {
            1
        } else {
            3 - value * 3
        }
    }
    
    var opacity: CGFloat {
        if value * 3 < 1 {
            1
        } else if value * 3 < 2 {
            (2 - value * 3)
        } else {
            1 - (3 - value * 3)
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        let angle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) * value
        content
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .opacity(opacity)
            .offset(x: radius * cos(angle), y: radius * sin(angle))
    }
}


Thanks. How did you obtain the 120 & 480 degree angle values?

@batman The way I calculate the offset means that 3 o’clock is 0 degrees (try plugging this into the sin and cos functions), so 7 o’clock is 120 degrees. Since we want a full rotation, the ending angle is 360 degrees more than that, so 480.

Understood. Thanks again!
